# ¿Cómo obtener objetos dentro de arrays anidados con javascript?

Tags: javascript

tengo un array que se ve de la siguiente manera:

```
contactos = 
[  
[ { persona1: 'juan', num: [ '333333' ] } ] 
[ {persona2: 'maría', num: [ '888888' ] } ] 
]
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener los objetos que están dentro de los arrays anidados y que se vean de la siguiente manera?

```
contactos = 
[ { persona1: 'juan', num: [ '333333' ] }, 
{persona2: 'maría', num: [ '888888' ] }
]
```

Intenté hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
    let filas = [];      
    
    for(let i=0; i< contactos.length; i++){
          filas.push(contactos[i])}
```

pero obtengo el mismo array original. gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta solución permite encapsular por clave y no separarlas (como seria el caso al usar `flat()`). Podría necesitar mantener al añadir nuevos valores, ejemplo:

```
let contactos = [
  [
    /**------------ */
    {
      persona1: 'juan',
      num: ['333333']
    },
    {
      ["persona1- alter"]: 'dam',
      num: ['333333']
    }
    /* ----------------*/
  ],
  [
    {
      persona2: 'maría',
      num: ['888888']
    },

  ],
];
```

**Solución:**

```
const filtroContactos = Object.entries(contactos)
  .flatMap(([_key, val]) => ([val]))
```

Convirtiendo el array en matriz, se usa flatMap(opcional)-desestructurando para aplanar la entrada al array de los valores originales.

Answer (score 2):

¡Hola!, es bastante sencillo, solo debes de usar el atributo para Arrays `[[]].flat()`

`flat()` lo que hará es eliminar arrays dentro de su array, como parámetro recibe la profundidad que tiene que eliminar, por ejemplo:

```js
const contactos = 
[  
[ { persona1: 'juan', num: [ '333333' ] } ] , //<- te faltaba esa coma
[ {persona2: 'maría', num: [ '888888' ] } ] 
];

const flat_contactos = contactos.flat();
console.log(flat_contactos);
```

Si no recibe parámetros, solo eliminará el primer array dentro.

¡Espero haberte ayudado, feliz hacking!

Comment: Esta solución funcionó muy bien, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Otra solución es que puedes usar el operador de propagación [`...` o Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) para descomponer el array `contactos`, es decir, extraer los valores de los arrays internos del array `contactos` (que son tus objetos), y luego concatenar el resultado en un array vacío:

```js
let contactos = [
  [ { persona1: 'juan', num: [ '333333' ] } ],
  [ { persona2: 'maría', num: [ '888888' ] } ]
];

let result = [].concat(...contactos);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Una pequeña modificación que puedes hacer al codigo que tienes para que funcione es agregar la primera entrada de cada subarreglo:

```
for(let i=0; i< contactos.length; i++){
   filas.push(contactos[i][0]);
}
```

Haciendo esto estarias la primera entrada de cada entrada del arreglo principal.